# Change default XTerm font size in Cygwin

Tags: configuration, cygwin, font-size, xterm

Anyone know how to change the default font size when you open a new XTERM windown in Cygwin?

I have found references of putting information into the ~/.Xresources file but that file doesn't exist for me...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Around ~2015 XWin Server was overhauled and you no longer need to create .startxwinrc because it no longer exists.  I found that the ~/.Xresources is read in automatically.  Also I found that XTerm.vt100.geometry is not valid anymore.

This is my .Xresources:

```
Xft*antialias:      true
Xft*autohint:       true
XTerm*background:   white  <== These settings mimics 
XTerm*foreground:   black      the default back, fore
XTerm*cursorColor:  grey       and cursor colors
XTerm*scrollBar:    true
XTerm*rightScrollBar:   false  <== This causes the scroll bar to be 
                                   on the default left side
XTerm*saveLines:    10000
XTerm*faceName:     BitStream Vera Sans Mono
XTerm*faceSize:     12
XTerm*toolBar:      On <== This causes the menu bar to appear with 
                           Main Options, VT Options, and VT Fonts
```

Answer (score 27):

here is how I fixed it:

1. Make sure your are in your home directory, so "cd" and "pwd" to see that you are there
2. Create the .Xresources file, just like "touch .Xresources"
3. Edit it with your favourite editor ;)
4. Here is my set up, it is actually very useful, it includes a side bar, and removes the top bar:

   ```
   Xft*antialias:          true
   Xft*autohint:           true
   XTerm*background:   black
   XTerm*foreground:   grey
   XTerm*cursorColor:  grey
   XTerm.vt100.geometry:   79x25
   XTerm*scrollBar:    true
   XTerm*rightScrollBar:   true
   XTerm*saveLines:    10000
   XTerm*faceName:     BitStream Vera Sans Mono
   XTerm*faceSize:     12
   XTerm*toolBar:      off
   ```
5. You can test this changes with "xrdb -merge .Xresources" and then opening another xterm
6. In order to save this changes you are going to have to create or modify another file, "touch .startxwinrc", open up your editor and include the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/sh

   xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
   ```
7. Restart your XWin Server, and you will have a prettier cygwin terminal.

Comment: Finally something that actually worked. If the xrdb command is not issues, the changes do not take effect.

Answer (score 5):

Gonzalo you made my day with your fix.
The font size can also be dynamically changed with the following keyboard shortcuts:

- **Shift+NumPadPlus** = Increase font size
- **Shift+NumPadMinus** = Decrease font size

Please take in account that the new font size is active for the current xterm window and that it is active for the current process session only. A new process will start with XTerm*faceSize sized fonts.

Comment: You can use Ctrl+Right Click (or Left Click) to get some options, including font options.